# issue with header fix in horizontal scroll in Datatable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I want a Datatable header fix so that I have done the below code

```html
<div class="table-responsive" >
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="Salesorder">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Quantity Ordered</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>EQP</th>
                <th>Item Value</th>
                <th>Ship Site</th>
                <th>Order #</th>
                <th>O_</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>Acct</th>
                <th>Suff</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Received Date</th>
                <th>Ship Code</th>
                <th>Ship Date</th>
                <th>Actual Ship Date</th>
                <th>Sales Representatives</th>
                <th>Order Commission</th>
                <th>Item Commission</th>
                <th>Customer P.O. Number</th>
                <th>Site Prod.</th>
                <th>Item Catalog</th>
                <th>#of impt</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             
              
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
var table = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
  "aaSorting": [],
  pageLength: 50,
  responsive: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTftigp'
});
```

I have to fix the Datatable header with `fixedHeader: true` it is working fine for vertical scroll but when I check with horizontal it is looking like [image] when I scroll it left to right it is still looking fix so that columns are getting mismatch. can anybody help me with this?

Comment: can you please  share your html codes as well?

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa please check

Comment: do you use `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-12 table-responsive">` ? because it's very ok for me